# when if i send Arabic characters means sql considering as 'question mark' why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Contains_Arabic_English_Char] ( @RowStr nvarchar(1000) ) 
RETURNS Char 
AS

BEGIN

declare @index int;
declare @charac char(1);
SELECT @index = 0;
declare @thisChar char(1);
while(@index <= LEN(@RowStr))
begin
 SELECT @thisChar = SUBSTRING(@RowStr,@index,1);

-- print @index
-- print ASCII(@thisChar) 
if (ASCII(@thisChar) BETWEEN 153 and 158 OR ASCII(@thisChar) BETWEEN 162 and 218 OR                                           ASCII(@thisChar) BETWEEN 223 and 254 )
--if (unicode(@thisChar) BETWEEN U+0600 and U+06FF)

begin SELECT @index=-1; 
BREAK;
 end 
else 
SELECT @index=@index+1; 
end 
-- print @index 
-- print LEN(@rowStr)
if (@index =-1)
BEGIN
SET @charac = 'A' --''found a Arabic char!'
END 
ELSE
BEGIN 
SET @charac = 'E' --'no Arabic Char found!' END

RETURN @charac

END

EXEC select [dbo].[Contains_Arabic_English_Char] ('ش')
```

it was showing ouput As "E"

so i have checked up like this manner

select ascii('ش')

it was given output as 63

63 is nothng but ascii value for Question mark '?"

Answer (score 2):

Try using UNICODE() instead of ASCII(), because you're dealing with unicode characters.

**ASCII():**

> Returns the ASCII code value of the
>   leftmost character of a character
>   expression.

**UNICODE()**:

> Returns the integer value, as defined
>   by the Unicode standard, for the first
>   character of the input expression.

Note, to run a test:

```
-- Returns 63:
select ASCII('ش')
-- Still returns 63:
select UNICODE('ش')
-- Returns 1588. Note the N before the character, to indicate it's a unicode string
select UNICODE(N'ش')
```

**Update:**
A few things you need to change:

```
declare @thisChar char(1);
```

should be:

```
declare @thisChar nchar(1);
```

Then when you check that character, just do a straight swap from using ASCII() to UNICODE()

Comment: It's worth calling attention to the distinction you show in your code example. `'ش'` is an ASCII string, so it does not contain the ش character (because that character does not exist in ASCII). Presumably, at some level before the actual `ASCII` function, the string was created as holding a question mark where you intended to have the ش, so what you passed to the `ASCII` function was in fact the string `'?'`. You must pass a *Unicode* string in order to have the ش character in it.

Comment: @Ada the DEV  ...i was confused that how to update your given changes to my procedure ..can yu pls help me

Comment: @Ada the DEV  .... IF I PASSING DIRECT STRING IT WAS COMMING CORRECT UNICODE (N''''+@ROWSTR+'''')  IT WAS NOT TAKING IF YOU GIV LIK THIS UNICODE(N'ش') IWAS WORKING

Comment: @Pubby - should work if you call the function like so: select [dbo].[Contains_Arabic_English_Char] (N'ش')

Comment: Note that character you are testing with returns 1588 from UNICODE(). That is NOT catered for in your IF conditions that do the checking on each character and results in you returning "E" - so you just need to adjust your condition check appropriately to make sure it's checking for the right range of characters